# Wordpress - Plugin for displaying code in posts [no shortcodes]

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and I need to display all sorts of coding examples within these posts, such as HTML, CSS, jQuery, PHP, C++, JavaScript, XML and a few others.

I have been looking around for plugins, but all the ones I can find, you have to insert the code in a separate page, choose the programming language, then paste the shortcode within your post which seems a bit time consuming. Is there any other way of displaying code for these languages so it uses the formatting and typical colours of the programming language.

At the moment, for speed I am just posting them as follows:-

```
<pre>
&lt;div class=&quot;logo logo-image&quot;&gt;

&lt;h3&gt;
    &lt;a href=&quot;http://url.co.uk&quot;&gt;
    &lt;img src=&quot;http://url.co.uk/images/03_logo-dark.png&quot; alt=&quot;Web-Tricks Logo&quot; /&gt;
    &lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/h3&gt;

&lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
```

Using [Postable](http://www.elliotswan.com/postable/) to replace the special characters so it doesn't interpret the text as HTML and doesn't display.

If anybody has a way I can improve this, a decent plugin I may have missed or whether or not this could be achieved in CSS let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a nice plugin in the end:-

[WP Code Prettify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-code-prettify/)

This plugin enable syntax highlighting of code snippets in your post using Google Code Prettify - and supports quite a load of different languages!

Also, with this plguin, you no longer have to use Postable to replace the special characters as it escapes all of this for you, so you just have to paste the code as it is.